# How to pass variable into function [ different file] using node js express

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm working on upload image . I following in document everything work fine but I just want to make a function more dynamic .

first I've my Controller

```
async function store (req, res) {
  const imgName = 'imgName';
    upload(req, res, imgName, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('eror');
        } else {
            console.log(req.file);
            res.send('test');
        }
    })

}
```

and in upload function I create new files names helpers.js

```
// Here i setup path and files name 
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './public/uploads/',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); }
    })

// the problem are here  imgName not define How can I pass variable into const upload
const upload = multer(imgName,{
    storage: storage
}).single(imgName');


module.exports = {
    upload,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to export a function `upload` not a prebuilt object:

```js
const upload = imgName => multer(imgName, { storage: storage }).single(imgName);

module.exports = { upload }
```

Then, your controller use by calling the function with imgName params

```js
async function store (req, res) {
  const imgName = 'imgName';
    upload(imgName)(req, res, imgName, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('eror');
        } else {
            console.log(req.file);
            res.send('test');
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: I got an error " Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated  " should I add async into upload  and call await upload ??

Comment: I think that the `multer` function returned by function `upload` is a Promise, then you must use it inside `try { ... } catch (e) { ... }` block, or adding a `.catch` function to prevent errors